# Is this variant of Facilities location problem a NP-hard problem?

Tags: np-hardness, proofs

Given a set of locations $P=\{p_1,p_2,\dots\}$ and a set of facilities $F=\{f_1,f_2,\dots\}，|F|\ge k$ on a plane. We want to partition the facilities into $k$ disjoint subsets (each subset has at least one facility). For each subset $F_i,i=1,2,\dots,k$, the cost of location $p\in P$ is the Euclidean distance between $p$ and its nearest facility in $F_i$. The cost of the subset $F_i$ is the sum of the cost of $p$, i.e. $Cost(F_i)=\sum_{p\in P}\min_{f\in F_i} Dis(p,f)$. The total cost is the sum of the costs of all subsets, i.e. $Cost=\sum_{i=1}^k Cost(F_i)$. I think it's an NP-hard problem. But I can't find a good proof.
In summary, the problem is:
$$
\begin{split}
\min_{F_1,F_2,\dots,F_k}\quad &\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{p\in P} \min_{f\in F_i}Dis(f,p)\\
subject\quad to\quad & F_i\cap F_j=\phi, i\neq j \\
\end{split}
$$

Is this an NP-hard problem?